# How to identify if the IdentityReference is a Group or a simpy a user

Tags: powershell-2.0

I manage to get the identityreference of a file as show below.

```
$arr=@((Get-Acl data.txt).Access|Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference)

for($i=0; $i -lt $arr.length ; $i++){ 
  $test=($arr[$i]).Value    ->The value $test needs to be checked if it Group Or User.

}
```

Is there way to identify if the IdentityReference is a Group or a simpy a user.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution you can use if Framework .NET 3.5 is installed on your computer and if you are using Active-Directory

```
$file = 'data.txt'

# Loading the assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

# Retreiving a principal context for the administrator
$domainContext = New-Object DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext([DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain, "VMESS01" , "jpb", "password")

try {
  $irefs=@((Get-Acl $file).Access|Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference)
  ForEach ($iref in $irefs)
  {
    $name = $iref.value.split("\\");
    $groupPrincipal = [DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($domainContext, [DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType]::Name, $name[1])

    if ($groupPrincipal -ne $null)
    {
      Write-Host "$iref is a group"
    }
    else
    {
      Write-Host "$iref is not a group"
    }
  }
}
catch
{
  $_
}
finally {
  $domainContext.Dispose()
}
```

Let it know if you've got other prerequisit ?

---

Edited :

Here is a solution using ADSI, You can use it from PowerShell V1.0. I do not solve the the case of NT Authority\SYSTEM a.k.a [LocalSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
Function IsGroup ($dn, $samAccountName)
{
  $rc= "NA"
  $Rech = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dn)
  $dumy = $Rech.filter = "((samAccountName=$samAccountName))"
  $dumy = $Rech.SearchScope = "subtree"
  $dumy = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectClass");
  $dumy = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectCategory");  

  $Object = $Rech.findone()
  if ($object -ne $null) 
  {
    if ($object.Properties["objectCategory"] -like "CN=Group,*")
    {
      $rc = $true
    }
    else
    {
      $rc = $false
    }
  }
  return $rc
}

Clear-Host

$dn = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://localhost:389/DC=SILOGIX-ESS01,DC=local","silogix@SILOGIX-ESS01.local","root.123;321.toor")

$arrs=@((Get-Acl 'data.txt').Access|Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference)

foreach ($arr in $arrs)
{
  $arr
  $netbiosName,$samAccountName = $arr -split '\\'
  write-host "$arr est un group : $(IsGroup $dn $samAccountName)"
}
```

Comment: Sure It's possible, first you can find the owner on the file itself, second in pure PowerShell you can use ADSI to access Active-Directory.

Comment: Hi JPBlanc,Thanks for the tips. I am only to use pure powershell. Basically, what I would like to do is to check if one specific user is an owner of the file. That's the reason why I need to check if that user is part of any group(s) based on the Identityreference. Do you think it is possible without using .Net ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi JPBlanc, thanks again. The result of my code above provides the owner/group of the file. I know in advance which specific user to check. So the next step is to check if the specific user is part of the group(s) that own the file based on identityreference). That;s I need to check if the identityreference is a group or not. If it is, then check if that group contains the specific user. By the way, the group does not have to be in Active-Diretory, it could be a ocal group on the machine like Adminitrators and other local groups. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi JPBlanc, do you have any suggestion to my last comments ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The code in my answer check if the name is a group. What else do you want to check ?

Comment: Hi JPBlanc, You asked me if I have the prerequiste Net 3.5. and I answeredI only need to use Powershell. So is it possible to do it on pwershell alone? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can do it using ADSI to access Active-Directory, it's still on the top of .NET, but use 2.0 version, the same as your PowerShell. I'll try to put an example today.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this snippet on my machine and it lists out group and user for each identity reference:

```
$arr=@((Get-Acl 'data.txt').Access|Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference)

for($i=0; $i -lt $arr.length ; $i++) { 
    #$test=($arr[$i]).Value    ->The value $test needs to be checked if it Group Or User.
    $name = $arr[$i].ToString().Split('\')[1];

    $obj = Get-ADObject -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $name}

    if ($obj) {
        $obj.ObjectClass
    }

}
```

Hope this works for you.